# Matlab dir showing empty struct

Tags: matlab

I have a folder `decawaveLogs` that has three subfolders of data files (.txt) - `longrange`, `shortrange` and `moving`. SO I did the following to access each subfolder data at a time

```
rangingType='longrange';


logsFolder = '/Users/X/Google Drive/rangingAccuracy\decawaveLogs'; %for Mac

decawaveFiles = dir(fullfile(logsFolder,rangingType,'*.txt'));
```

When I run the complete program, I get en empty struct for `decawaveFiles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing forward and backward slashes in logFolder. That might be an issue.